# which is better: write a php/mysql code or make a mysql trigger between a start datetime and end datetime?

Tags: php, mysql

I've been confused what's much better is to write code for the datetime between start datetime and end datetime or make a mysql trigger?? I have a Mysql table named "Bid" it contains
Table: "Bid"

```
COL1: Bid_ID (PK)  
COL2: Bid_ITEMNAME VARCHAR(100)  
COL3: Bid_ITEMDESCRIPTION VARCHAR(100)  
COL4: Bid_STARTDATETIME DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  
COL5: Bid_ENDDATETIME DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  
COL6: Bid_Status varchar(25) DEFAULT 'PENDING'  
COL7: Bid_Price int
```

Example: STARTDATETIME : 14/12/2021 6:03:00 PM
ENDDATETIME: 14/12/2021 7:30:00 PM

When endatetime reaches the bid_status will be update as 'expired'

If it's better to write it on code or MySQL trigger then how?

Comment: *what's much better is to write code for the datetime between start datetime and end datetime or make a mysql trigger* None. You need in EVENT procedure.

Comment: That information is basically redundant. The status is linked with the endtime, and if it's not updated exactly on time, it can be logically out of sync. So, just omit that status column and *infer* whether a bid is expired from the current time and the end time…?!